# Check if Mage.exe batch manifest update was successful or not - ClickOnce

Tags: vb.net, batch-file, console-application, clickonce, mage

I have created a console app that creates a batch file in code, that will automatically update and re-sign my app manifest file using mage.exe when a new version gets published.

This batch file then gets executed by the same console app after it has created it.

I want to know if there is a way to determine if the mage.exe batch file failed in updating or signing the manifest?

Any help or ideas will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

As per  *TnTinMn*'s comment, I forced the batch to fail on updating the manifest. This returned a exit code of 1. How is it then possible for me to extract that exit code to do my error handling? Im doing the following:

```
Dim procInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
procInfo.UseShellExecute = True
procInfo.FileName = (sDriveLetter & ":\updatemanifest.bat")
procInfo.WorkingDirectory = ""
procInfo.Verb = "runas"
procInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Dim sval As Object = Process.Start(procInfo) 'I tested the object to see if there is indeed a value that i can use.
```

While debugging and looking at the sval object's properties, the exit code is set to 1 but i can't seem to extract it from there.

Comment: Does Mage return an exit code on failure?  If so, check the ErrorLevel in the batch file.

Comment: @TnTinMn thanks for the tip. I have updated my question.

Comment: What does this mean:  `looking at the sval object's properties, the exit code is set to 1 but i can't seem to extract it from there`.  It is not clear what your current issue is?  It may also be to your advantage to show the content of updatemanifest.bat.

Comment: Use the Process.ExitCode property.  Any value other than 0 indicates that the process did not complete normally.  Error code values depend on the specific process and are not standardized.

Comment: @TnTinMn Sorry for not making it clear. I set the sval object equal to the Process.Start that I initiate. In debug, I explored the sval object and and one of the properties is ExitCode which is then equal to 1 when an error occurred. In short i want to do the following: 

`if sval.exitcode = 1 then messagebox.show("an error occured") else messagebox.show("successful")`

The problem is not in the mage.exe batch file. I just want to handle an error should one occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways (that I know of) that you can wait for the process to exit before retrieving the Process.ExitCode.

The first as is a blocking call: `Process.WaitForExit`

and the second is to use the `Exit` event.

```
Private Sub RunProcess()
    Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo()
    psi.UseShellExecute = True
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    psi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    psi.Arguments = "/c Exit 100"


    Dim proc As Process = Process.Start(psi)
    proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
    AddHandler proc.Exited, AddressOf ProcessExited
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessExited(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim proc As Process = DirectCast(sender, Process)
    proc.Refresh()
    Dim code As Int32 = proc.ExitCode
    Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Process has exited with code: {0}", code)), Nothing)
    proc.Dispose()
End Sub
```